# How to Add/Sub current value of a field in OneClick Rule?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am trying to burn my time in OneClick. So I am creating OneClick rule to reduce 6 hours from Remaining Time, Add 6 hours in Completed Time and Save.

Problem is, I can't find a way to Add/Sub current value of a field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesnot support mathematical operation right now. Please refer to the open issue for [one click](https://github.com/mohitbagra/vsts-extensions/issues/49) extension. 
You can also submit the issue directly to the extension author there.

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom extension to do this? Any guidance on it?

Comment: Custom extension might be able to do it. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops) to create a custom extension